# MySQL inner join a count from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do a `SELECT` query in MySQL which will also do a `count` in another table and `join` the answer into my initial `table`

Table `people`

id | name | hair_color | job_id

Table `job`

id | job_name

```
SELECT * 
FROM job j
INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(job_id) AS totals
           FROM people p
           WHERE p.job_id='1')
     ON j.count = totals
WHERE id = '1'
ORDER BY id ASC
```

So I am trying to get the above query to Select from my `job` table by the `id` and also do a `count` in the `people` table and add the column `count` to my `job` result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to make the count in the subquery : you can directly select count and then group by. Moreover, you don't have to manually precise the `people` `job_id` : a JOIN is made directly between two tables fields (minimum).

```
SELECT j.id, j.job_name, count(p.id) as nb_people
  FROM job j
       INNER JOIN people p ON p.job_id = j.id
 WHERE j.id = '1'
GROUP BY j.id, j.job_name
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Have a look at MySQL aggregate functions documentation : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

And maybe another look on JOIN documentation : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: Upvoted, but I'd make it `COUNT(DISTINCT p.id)` just in case :)

Comment: I personnally prefer `COUNT(1)`, but you are right that's clearer for beginners. I edit my answer, thanks.

Comment: @OlivierH what does the `1` represent inside the brackets?

Comment: If you make, for example, `SELECT 1 FROM people`, it will return you a '1' character for each line found. Here, use `COUNT(1)` or `COUNT(p.id)` does the same thing : count the number of lines found. Use 1 is a common pratice, slightly more performant.